# What does it mean when conditional mean is linear in predictors?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am trying to understand this equation:

> If conditional mean is linear in $x$, so that $E[y|x] = x'\beta$...

I don't understand why conditional mean ($E[y|x]$) should be equal to $x'\beta$ if its linear in predictors.

Also if conditional mean is non linear in predictors why would it lose structural or causal interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why conditional mean ($E[y|x]$) should be equal to
>   $x'\beta$ if its linear in predictors.

It does not have be equal to it. It can have any form. Using linear regression is just one of many ways to approximate conditional mean. You can choose to use it as model, you can choose something else.

> Also if conditional mean is non linear in predictors why would it lose
>   structural or causal interpretation?

Even if it is linear, it does not tell you anything about causality. I don't know what you mean by "structural interpretation".